# SQL split a result properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a result from a request that gives me thousands of lines, and i want to split it into little temporary tables of 10k rows each, with an incremental number from 1 up to 10 000. Lets say i have a big query of 25 000 rows, what i want is to split it in 2 tables of 10k and a third table of 5k. Of course I dont know that exact number of pages i will have to split into.

> My first query with all the rows is named [#DECLARATION] and have a number NumeroDeclaration that is 0 for page 1, 1 for page 2, etc. to 9. Each 10 000 of rows it is incremented from 0 to 10 000.

at this time my request looks like this:

```
    --Page 1
    SELECT * INTO [#PAGE1] FROM [#DECLARATION] WHERE NumeroDeclaration =0 ORDER BY NumeroTransaction;
        --Numerotation
        WITH upd AS (SELECT NumeroDeclaration, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NumeroTransaction) AS Numtemp FROM [#PAGE1])
        UPDATE upd SET NumeroDeclaration = Numtemp
    --Page 2
    SELECT * INTO [#PAGE2] FROM [#DECLARATION] WHERE NumeroDeclaration =1 ORDER BY NumeroTransaction;
        --Numerotation
        WITH upd AS (SELECT NumeroDeclaration, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NumeroTransaction) AS Numtemp FROM [#PAGE2])
        UPDATE upd SET NumeroDeclaration = Numtemp
    --Page 3
    --etc.... to Page 10...
```

**I have to do this over 10 pages, and it works, but is there another *shorter*/classier way to do it?**

Im using SQL SERVER 2008 Thanks for reading

Comment: why split it to temporary tables and not just select the group of rows you want each time ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli because after I split it into smaller tables i have to write a headline from each table and then implant it all together into business object. I know i could use an easy python script to export it into .csv but I am not allowed to :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure why you need to split to smaller tables and you can't use filters on the single `[#DECLARATION]` table.

You queries imply that the `[#DECLARATION]` table is already partitioned to pages through the `NumeroDeclaration` column.

You could do

```
Declare @recordsPerPage AS int
SELECT @recordsPerPage = 10000;
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NumeroDeclaration ORDER BY NumeroTransaction ASC) AS Tempnum,
    NumeroDeclaration+1 AS Page
FROM numbered
```

This will bring a resultset with embedded `page` page column and `Tempnum` column which will reset for each page.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your help but still i will have to write 10 times  "select * into [#PageX] from Y where Page=X". Anyway i think that doing a view or a temporary table like your answer is nice. **The final aim is actually to export every 10k rows into a csv file through Business Object with a first line calculated over the 10k rows informations.** Still, your answer is cute because it spares me the update x10